# External devices not detected in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: keyboard, mouse, 22.04, external-monitor

I'm quite new to Linux and I've started using Ubuntu 22.04 since the past 2 days.

I tried connecting my external monitor to it and it did not seem to be detected. I looked around for some solutions and I tried reinstalling nvidia drivers and restarted my PC (keeping my monitor connected). It was detected then, but I got the problem again after disconnecting my monitor.

I also noticed I have problems with other devices like my Headphones, Mouse, Keyboard etc. Not sure if this matters, but my Keyboard and mouse are connected through a KM switch.

I wasn't able to find any solution for this. So, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure the switch is not the issue? Is it just a switch for keyboard and monitor or does it do the video as well?

Comment: @David It's just a switch for the Keyboard and the mouse. The monitor is connected directly through an HDMI cable. I now tried to change the NVIDIA driver to a proprietary one, instead of the open source one. It seemed to work once, but I still need to test it out a few times.